# Decimal being Rounded when Imported in SSIS

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, ssis, decimal, rounding

I'm struggling to import some data in SSIS into SQL Server 2008 R2.

The datatype of the excel source is set as `DT_NUMERIC` with a precision of `18` and a scale of `2`.

I've set a data viewer just before the data goes into the OLE DB Destination which shows the number correctly formatted as in the picture below:

[image: Example Data]

When querying the column in SSMS, the results are not expected as they are either left at 0.00 or have been rounded to 1.00. The datatype of the field of the table is `Decimal(18,2)` and the output column in the advanced settings of the destination is also set as `DT_NUMERIC` with a precision of `18` and a scale of `2`.

Could anyone help me with why this is occurring?

Comment: Could you confirm that the column is correctly mapped at the destination?  i.e. does the score column have a transformation in which the values are transferred to an integer column?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz There's no transformation for the `score` field and it's pointed towards the `score` field in the table which has a datatype of `Decimal(18,2)`. Thanks

Comment: is this being affected by the excel TypeGuessRows setting which takes a sampling of the first 8 rows and guesses the data type at run time?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz It shouldn't do as with the sample data here, the first rows are as in the picture above.

Comment: Could you clear the destination table and confirm no prior runs are mucking up the results?  Also, have a look at SQL Profiler during the execution to confirm what values are being inserted.

Comment: Thanks @MarkWojciechowicz. After clearing the table and re-running the package, the values successfully updated.

Comment: Cool. I'll bet the issue was just that there was other bad data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

On your Excel sheet, mark the column as text with formatting to allow 2 decimal places, once that is completed, you will be able to convert the data to appropriate type.

On a second note, right click on the Excel source and select "Advanced Editor". Surf to the Input/Output tab and on the second "+" sign (from top), see what the data type is for your column. You can make changes here too to allow for the precision. If I were you and facing issues, I'd rather convert to varchar and reconvert it back to float to avoid loosing any decimals.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was temporary table with decimal column created, but I forgot to point the precision, so SQL Server created decimal(18,0) and silently rounded all the values...